# error in ajax isn't being hit

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using ajax to send values from my view to a controller in my application.

**Ajax:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#SendToController').on('click', function() {
    sendToController();
    return false;
});
function sendToController(){
    var selectedM = $('#Month').val();
    var chosenY = $('#Year').val();
    var chosenC = $('#County').val();
    //alert(chosenY);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/ALog/MReports/Generate',
        data: { 'monthV' : selectedM, 'year' : chosenY, 'county' : chosenC },
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("body").html(data);
            $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
        },
        error: function () {
            if (selectedM === "") {
                alert("Error 1!");
            }
            else if (chosenY === "") {
                alert("Error 2!");
            }
            else if (chosenC === "") {
                alert("Error 3!");
            }
        }
    });
}


</script>
```

Now, on my form i have 3 dropdownlists which I am getting the values from in the ajax code above.  The only time the ajax function goes to the `error` part is if `chosenC` and/or `selectedM` is empty, but if `chosenY` is empty it still goes to `success`.

I have alerted the value of `chosenY` when I left it blank to ensure that I am checking for the right value with javascript, either `null` or empty (`""`).. I have tried both, and neither work..

Here is the result from when I alerted the `chosenY`

[image]

so from that I thought it was an empty string.. so I am checking for that.. but it doesn't matter because even if it is empty the ajax method is considering that as a `success` and not an `error`.. why is that?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why would an empty response be an error?

Comment: error/success is based on http status codes. If the service you're hitting is a 2xx OK-type response, the it goes to `success`.

Comment: @epascarello because without that data, then the result is an empty table.  I need that field to be required

Comment: So check to see if data was returned before you set the html.

Comment: @MarcB okay, so why is it hitting those status codes when `chosenY` is empty but it doesn't hit those status codes when either `chosenC` or `selectedM` is empty?

Comment: how should we know? You've shown nothing of what happens on the server.

Comment: I don't see how this possible work without event delegation (`$("body").html(data);`). And don't pass a request to the server when you know it will return an error, what's the point in all that roundup? To make things easier and to let us help you, include the server side and the html too

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid, try to alert `chosenY` like this: `alert('"' + chosenY + '"');` and tell what you get.

Comment: please, show your `html` and some of your backend code, so we can analyze it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MarcB I figured this out.  It was in fact on the server side, and it wasn't throwing an error because it was using that value to search for records in the database table even though it was empty string.

So i just converted the string to an `int` which would throw an exception if year is passed as an empty string.

Thanks again for the ideas/help!